# Decoding Analytics report's obfuscated (Proguard) exception location

Tags: exception, google-analytics, proguard

Lines from my 'Exception Description' from Google Analytics 'Crashes and Exceptions' report include:

```
IllegalArgumentException (@ak:g:-1) {Thread-8609}
IllegalStateException (@w:a:-1) {main}
```

I'm trying to decode them with the Proguard GUI as the Proguard mapping file is 33693 lines long, including hundreds of '-> ak' and '->w' lines. I've tried editing the exception lines down and adding a 'proguard.' preface without any luck:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now another way to decode obfuscated exception reports.

If you connect your app to the new Firebase developer platform and add Firebase Analytics to your code, you will get access to the Firebase Developer Console. If you click the 'Crash Reporting' tab, it will give you a detailed list of your crashes, including app version number. Click on any of the crash listings and you will get a full trace, including an 'Upload a ProGuard mapping file to deobfuscate future stack traces for version xxx' message. Click the 'UPLOAD' button and browse to your 'mapping.txt' file. Upload the file and, voilà, the trace is decoded.

If you've never browsed to your 'mapping.txt' file, it's well buried at 'app/build/outputs/mapping/release'.

Configuring and coding for Firebase and Firebase Analytics I'll leave to the Docs, and to Stack Overflow if you have issues.